# how to inject a env variables in a common.tfvars

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

how to inject a env variables in a common.tfvars file

ex

```
export TF_VAR_ENV="test"
```

and use this in a common.tfvars

```
environment         = "{get_env("TF_VAR_ENV", "")}" /// i don't know what is good syntax for that
```

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: Why not just use the `ENV` variable in Terraform directly? Or `export TF_VAR_environment=test`?

Comment: do you have a other solution for my problem ?

Comment: You can't do what you want but I'm asking if there's a reason you can't use either of the other options I suggested.